# How to copy a python object/ How to get element of a python object

Tags: matplotlib, geometry, python-3.6

#### Question 1:

I need to make a copy of one circle I create

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
```

I want to do something like:

```
C2 = C1.copy()
```

To be able to modify C2 without modifying C1 but I get the error:

```
'AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'copy''
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

#### Question 2:

I try to get the element of C1

```
xy = C1.xy
```

> AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'xy'

```
color = C1.color
```

> AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'color'

For xy, I manage to get it by doing

```
xy = C1.center
```

But I do not understand why I have to use center even if I declare it as 'xy'. For color I still don't know how to get it... I thin it is probably a characteristic of a parent object (not specific to the circle object) but how to get it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two completely different questions.

#### Copy

You may copy any python element using `copy`.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from copy import copy

C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
C2 = copy(C1)

print(C1 == C2)  # prints False
```

#### Attriutes

Instead of accessing the attributes directly, matplotlib artists provide getters/setters for most of its attributes.

```
C1.get_facecolor()
C1.get_edgecolor()
C1.get_radius()
```

It is indeed a little inconsistent that the Circle does not have a `.get_center` method. So to get the center use

```
C1.center
```

#### Replicate Artist

In order to replicate an artist, you may use its `update_from` method. This will copy all the styling at once from once artist to the other. It will not update its position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
C2=Circle(xy=(1, 2), radius=1, fill=True, color='b')

plt.gca().add_patch(C1)
plt.gca().add_patch(C2)

C1.update_from(C2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still got just one question... How to get the color.... "C1.get_color()" did not work....

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'get_color'"

Comment: And one last question: what is the difference between copy and replicate an artist??? Copy seems much more easier :-). Would I have a difference between a C2 from "copy" and a C2 from update_from?

Comment: Yes sorry, there is no `get_color` , only `set_color`. Because it would not be clear if you want to get the facecolor or the edgecolor. The difference between copy and update_from is as said that update_from does not copy the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
```

To get the color 'b' of the circle:

```
C1.get_edgecolor()
```